# Selecting a specific row from two joined tables in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How would I go about selecting a specific row in a mySQL table?

Comment: WHERE person.person_id = '102'. You need to add the table alias.

Comment: Assuming both tables have a column person_id

Answer (score 1):

It's generally good form to remove ambiguity by referencing the table associated with every field in the select.

Then you also reference the table in the WHERE as well:

```
SELECT
    person.person_id,
    person.last_name,
    patient.date_registered /* I am assuming this is value from patient table */
FROM person 
INNER JOIN patient
ON person.person_id=patient.patient_id
WHERE person.person_id = 102;
```

You can also alias the fields if you want better key names in the result set for your application:

```
SELECT
    person.person_id AS `person_id`,
    person.last_name AS `last_name`,
    patient.date_registered AS `date_registered`
FROM person 
INNER JOIN patient
ON person.person_id=patient.patient_id
WHERE person.person_id = 102;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the  `person_id` is numeric.

```
SELECT person.person_id, last_name, date_registered 
FROM person 
INNER JOIN patient
ON person.person_id=patient.patient_id;
WHERE person.person_id = 102
```

if no, use:

```
WHERE person.person_id = '102'
```